# How to upload files to Google drive Shared drive folder?

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

Actually this code is uploading files to  normal Gdrive but i need to upload my files into the shared drive can anyone help me. All i need is to Upload my files to to my shared drive. Below is my current code :-

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Client;
use Google\Service\Drive;
# TODO - PHP client currently chokes on fetching start page token
function uploadBasic()
{
    try {
        $client = new Client();
        putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=./credentials.json');
        $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
        $client->addScope(Drive::DRIVE);
        $driveService = new Drive($client);

        $file = getcwd().'/637fdc0994855.mp4';
        $filename = basename($file);
        $mimeType = mime_content_type($file);

        $fileMetadata = new Drive\DriveFile(array(
            'name' => $filename,
            'parents' => ['1VBi8C04HBonM6L4CfL-jHWZ0QoQRyrCL']
        ));
        $content = file_get_contents('637fdc0994855.mp4');
        $file = $driveService->files->create($fileMetadata, array(
            'data' => $content,
            'mimeType' => $mimeType,
            'uploadType' => 'multipart',
            'fields' => 'id'
        ));
        printf("File ID: %s\n", $file->id);
        return $file->id;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Error Message: " . $e;
    }
}
uploadBasic();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to upload the file to the shared drive, please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
$file = $driveService->files->create($fileMetadata, array(
    'data' => $content,
    'mimeType' => $mimeType,
    'uploadType' => 'multipart',
    'fields' => 'id'
));
```

#### To:

```
$file = $driveService->files->create($fileMetadata, array(
    'data' => $content,
    'mimeType' => $mimeType,
    'uploadType' => 'multipart',
    'fields' => 'id',
    'supportsAllDrives' => true // <--- Added
));
```

#### Note:

- In this case, your client has no permission for writing the shared drive, an error occurs. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [Files: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)

Comment: sir after adding that this error came :- (  Error Message: Google\Service\Exception: { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "usageLimits", "reason": "userRateLimitExceeded", "message": "User rate limit exceeded." } ], "code": 403, "message": "User rate limit exceeded." } } in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Http\REST.php  )

Comment: can you help me to solve the above error

Comment: @jasonzs About `userRateLimitExceeded` and `can you help me to solve the above error`, I would like to support you. About this, in your question, you say `Actually this code is uploading files to normal Gdrive`. I understood that your script works fine for uploading the file to your Google Drive. If my understanding is correct, how about testing the modified script 1 day later? By the way, when I tested my proposed script, I confirmed that the file is uploaded to a folder in the shared Drive. So, please don't worry.

Comment: Sir the error is still the same I dont know how to fix it please help me

Comment: @jasonzs Thank you for replying. About `Sir the error is still the same I dont know how to fix it please help me`, first, I have to confirm your current situation. In your question, you say `Actually this code is uploading files to normal Gdrive`. Your showing script works fine and you can upload a file to your Google Drive. Is my understanding correct? Because, when your showing script works, the modified script works. I apologize for this.

Comment: Sir I am really grateful that you helped me but the thing is that when I upload the file to the normal Drive it works fine but the error comes only when I choose the ID of my Shared Drive.

Comment: @jasonzs Thank you for replying. About `but the thing is that when I upload the file to the normal Drive it works fine but the error comes only when I choose the ID of my Shared Drive.`, in your script, when your script is run, a file can be uploaded. But, when `'supportsAllDrives' => true` is added to your script, an error of `userRateLimitExceeded` occurs. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes sir thats what happened. But I tried to upload to another shared drive in one of my other google accounts this code works fine but I only get this error when uploading to the shared drive in this account ( I dont know why is that ) I even tried again by creating another service account but nothing changed still getting this error.

Comment: @jasonzs Thank you for replying. From `But I tried to upload to another shared drive in one of my other google accounts this code works fine`, it is found that my proposed answer was correct. About `but I only get this error when uploading to the shared drive in this account`, in this case, I think that it might be related to the permission. So, it might not be related to this question. So, I would like to recommend posting it as a new question.

Comment: @jasonzs Thank you for replying. From `But I tried to upload to another shared drive in one of my other google accounts this code works fine`, it is found that my proposed answer was correct. So, in this case, please accept this answer. I think that your question will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Comment: @jasonzs Thank you for your response. About your new issue of `but I only get this error when uploading to the shared drive in this account`, I think that it might be related to the permission. Please confirm it again. When the issue was not resolved by confirming the permission, I would like to recommend posting it as a new question. By this, it will help users including me think of the solution.

Comment: Ok sir I recheck permissions.

Comment: How do you specify which shared folder to upload to? I don't understand

Comment: @Timberman About your question of `How do you specify which shared folder to upload to? I don't understand`, I would like to support you. So, can you post it as a new question by including more information? By this, it will help users including me think of a solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?